# How is Jam Factor computed?

Tags: here-api

How is Jam Factor (JF) in Here API's traffic info computed?
-    How does this relate to the traffic flow volume?

Please note: I am not asking for the interpretation of Jam Factor. I understand the green, yellow, red, black zone interpretation. My question the regarding the exact math behind it.

Answer (score 0):

We wont be able to provide you the calculation behind JF. It is complex and not made visible to freemium users. If you have a paid plan please approach your sales contact.

"JF" = The number between 0.0 and 10.0 indicating the expected quality of travel. When there is a road closure, the Jam Factor will be 10. As the number approaches 10.0 the quality of travel is getting worse. -1.0 indicates that a Jam Factor could not be calculated